# Index Error: list index out range

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm working with Enthought canopy Python 2.7.9.
A very simple Python program that involves `for`, `range`, and `len`:

```
num = 10
mylist = range(num)
for i in range(len(mylist)):
  print "Size of mylist is %d" %(len(mylist))
  print "i=%d" %(i)
  print "mylist[%d] %d" %(i, mylist[i])
  mylist=mylist[:-1]
```

What puzzles me is that since the length of `mylist` has decreased to 5, why index `i` can still be 5, leading to the index error?

I know in Python a for-loop works with an iterable. But I do not know how this mechanism works in this example.

Comment: As a side note, you should generally use the more idiomatic `for item in my_list`. Check out `enumerate()` if you also need and index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never change the size of a list while iterating over it. Remove this line:

```
mylist=mylist[:-1]
```

and it will work.

The length of the list is only determine once here:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
```

and `i` will take on all values from `0` through `9`. When you change the size of the list later, the length will not be recalculated.

Comment: To add to what Mike is saying here, at the start of the loop `my_list` is an identifier for a list of 10 items. Since you're using `len()` on that list, your loop will iterate 10 times. But inside the loop, you are reassigning the `my_list` identifier to point to a smaller and smaller list each iteration.